# ANSI C program error: pointer address initializes fine, then changes to 0x0 after an if statement

Tags: c

I have an ANSI C program in Linux CentOS 64-bit computer containing the following lines:

```
H1_real = malloc(len_SPURFREQ_TIE * sizeof(double)); /* allocate memory */
H1_imag = malloc(len_SPURFREQ_TIE * sizeof(double)); /* allocate memory */
H2_real = malloc(len_SPURFREQ_TIE * sizeof(double)); /* allocate memory */
H2_imag = malloc(len_SPURFREQ_TIE * sizeof(double)); /* allocate memory */
H3_real = malloc(len_SPURFREQ_TIE * sizeof(double)); /* allocate memory */
H3_imag = malloc(len_SPURFREQ_TIE * sizeof(double)); /* allocate memory */

if ( (H1_real == NULL) || (H1_imag == NULL) || (H2_real == NULL) || (H2_imag == NULL) || (H3_real == NULL) || (H3_imag = NULL) ) {
exit(6);
}
```

When I use gdb to check the allocated addresses of H1_real to H3_imag, they look fine. The if statement also executes fine, in that exit(6) is not triggered. But when checking the H3_imag address after the if statement executes, it now read 0x0. Anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: Only the H3_imag address is set to 0x0 ?

Comment: It's possible that the variable only exists temporarily when needed.  If you don't use them after the if statement, the compiler could generate code where whatever was holding them previously gets clobbered.  Are they declared locally on the stack or globally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
H3_imag = NULL
```

is supposed to be:

```
H3_imag == NULL
```

Comment: Part of the top 5 of C typos :P In any case, the compiler should warn about that.

Comment: @moshbear I've hever had any compiler (neither gcc on its highest error settings that I know of nor MSVC++) warn about that.

Comment: How embarrassing (!) Thanks so much Mystical!

Comment: No compiler warning in my case.

Comment: @ggkmath: Enable compiler warnings. `-Wall`. (Ok, probably won't help here since the assignment *is* bracketed in () already).

Comment: @SethCarnegie gcc as of 4.5 does that on -Wall, specifically 'warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]'. As a rule, assignment and truth in the same sentence is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Typecasting the return value of `malloc` to the appropriate type is a good practice.. For example: if the type of your `H1_real` is double *, then the following would be a nice.

```
H1_real = (double *) malloc(len_SPURFREQ_TIE * sizeof(double)); /* allocate memory */
```

The same applies to all the variables which gets their memory allocated using `malloc` (which returns a void *).

Comment: Is there any benefit to this if the code will never port to C++? That is, it will forever remain compiled as ansi C?

Comment: Making explicit cast when dealing with void * is a preferred coding practice in most of the C coding guidelines that I've came across.. There are advantages and disadvantages to this approach. This is very well captured in this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Type_safety).